# Add Points to Geopandas Object

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, geopandas

My objective is to create some kind of geojson object and add several **Point**'s objects to it, with a **For** Loop.

What am I missing here?

```
from geojson import Feature
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
# Point((-115.81, 37.24))

# Create a Dataframe with **Schools Centroids**
myManipulationObj = pd.DataFrame
for schoolNumber in listOfResults:
    myManipulationObj.append(centroids[schoolNumber])

# GDF should be a Beautiful collection (geoDataFrame) of Points
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(myManipulationObj, geometry='Coordinates')
```

After that, I want to use geopandas write() to create a .geojson file.

Any Help?

---

(solved)

I solved that problem by:

1. creating a python list (**listOfPoints**),
2. Using the POINT object as geometry parameter to the FEATURE object,
3. Using the List of Features (with Points) to create a FeatureCollection

Leave here for future reference if someone needs :D

```
# Used to get the Index of Schools from the M Model Optimized
listOfResults = []
for e in range(numSchools):
    tempObj = m.getVarByName(str(e))
    # If This School is on the Results Optimized
    if(tempObj.x != 0):
        listOfResults.append(int(tempObj.varName))

 # Select, from the List Of Results, A set of Centroid Points 
 listOfPoints = []
 for schoolNumber in listOfResults:
     # Attention to the Feature(geometry) from geopandas
     listOfPoints.append(Feature(geometry=centroids[schoolNumber]))

 # Creating a FeatureCollection with the Features (Points) manipulated above
 resultCentroids = FeatureCollection(listOfPoints)
```

Comment: What is the step you are getting stuck? Can you make the problem more specific, or provide a reproducible example (http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was missing the Feature(geometry=POINT) thing. Did not notice that I could use a list to store the objects, and then turn them into a featureCollection

Comment: Indeed, I needed that. Thanks!